# trying to print an object and returns null

Tags: java

so i wrote a code that is suposed to grab lines from a txt file and create an object with the data and add that object to an array list but when i try to print the object something weird happens.
This is the main class:

```
public class Main{
    static ArrayList<profesor>profesors = new ArrayList<profesor>();
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
        readList();
        for(int i=0;i<profesors.size(); i++){
            String p = profesors.get(i).toString();
            System.out.println(p);

        }

        fillTimetable();
        displayTimetable();


    }
    private static void readList() throws Exception {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("list.txt");
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(file);
        String line =reader.readLine();
        String lineSplit[]= new String[27];
        while(line != null){
            lineSplit = line.split("\\s+");
            profesors.add(new profesor(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1], new String[]{ lineSplit[2], lineSplit[3], lineSplit[4], lineSplit[5], lineSplit[6], lineSplit[7],lineSplit[8], lineSplit[9], lineSplit[10], lineSplit[11], lineSplit[12], lineSplit[13], lineSplit[14], lineSplit[15], lineSplit[16], lineSplit[17], lineSplit[18], lineSplit[19], lineSplit[20], lineSplit[21], lineSplit[22], lineSplit[23], lineSplit[24], lineSplit[25], lineSplit[26]}));
            line = reader.readLine();

        }

    }
    private static void fillTimetable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    private static void displayTimetable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

this its the profesor class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class profesor {
    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private String[] avalidehours=new String[25];

    public profesor(String string, String string2, String[] strings) {

        string = name;
        string2 = subject;
        strings = avalidehours;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name + subject + Arrays.toString(avalidehours);
    }

}
```

the txt:

```
Petittsdfi  Mateasdfmatica  mif mig vif vig ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Csdfales    Apeasddsca  luc lud mac mad mic mid juc jud ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Lucsdfdfero NavasdsdegacionI    lub luc lud lue mab mac mad mae mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue vib vic vid vie ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Bergamaschi TecPasdsdesc    lua luf maa maf mia mif jua juf via vif ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Mazzssa MeteoasffrologiaI   mab mac jub juc ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Puesdfdla   ComunicaasdcionesI  lua lub luc lud maa mab mac mad mia mib mic mid jua jub juc jud via vib bic bid ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Chifdsatti  IngTasddecI mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Jimesdfdfnez    Superviasdfvencia   maa mab jua jub ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Rusbissno   ManasddiobraI   mab mac mad mae maf mib mic mid mie mif ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Veldfsasco  MaquinasI   vib vic vid vie vif ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ  ññ
Luscsro EquiposElectronicos lub luc lud lue mab mac mad mae mib mic mid mie jub juc jud jue vib vic vid vie ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ
Ateasdnas PrimerosAux vib vic vid vie ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ
Fustafer CargaasfEstiva lue luf lug mae maf mag mie mif mig jue juf jug vie vif vig  ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ ññ
```

and this its the what i get when i run the program:

```
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
nullnull[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: Start debugging your own work and come back when you have a question.

Answer (score 4):

```
public profesor(String string, String string2, String[] strings) {

    string = name;
    string2 = subject;
    strings = avalidehours;
}
```

should be

```
public profesor(String string, String string2, String[] strings) {

    this.name  = string;
    this.subject  = string2;
    this.avalidehours = strings;
}
```

You shouldreally, really consider choosing better variable naes, respecting the Java naming conventions, and use loops rather thanenumerating the 25 avalidehours elements one by one.

Also, use the try-with-resources statement when reading a file to ensure the readers are closed when you're done reading.

Comment: I don't think the "this" call should be required when referencing local privates with different names to passed vars, still give it a go!

Comment: It isn't, but the point of using it is to make it clear that the constructor initializes fields from arguments, rather than initializing arguments from fields. The traditional way of doing is to name arguments the same way as fields, and to use `this.foo = foo;`.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed the assignations in your `profesor` constructor :

```
string = name;
```

Should be

```
name = string;
```